# LESS - import a file but not print it

Tags: css, less

I need to compile a LESS file and mix in some of the classes used in other files, but I don't want to print the whole contents of the imported files.

This looks pretty much like silent selectors in SASS.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"muted" imports are not yet implemented in the current stable version of less (1.4.2 as of as of this post), but are planned for inclusion in 1.5.0. [source @github issues](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1210)

They don't seem to be working in the current beta, but when they are finally baked in, the implementation should like this:

**PSEUDO CODE**

**reference.less:**

```
.not-awesome {
  color: red;
}

.awesome {
 color: blue;
}
```

**main.less:**

```
@import (mute) "foo.less";

.more-awesome:extend(.awesome){
  font-size:8em;
}
```

**output:**

```
.awesome,
.more-awesome {
  color: blue;
}
.more-awesome {
  font-size: 8em;
}
```